# Namespaced Routes give me Unitialized constant Admin::Towers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

The two particular routes im having issues with are admin/inspections and admin/activities. When I first save routes.rb, whichever route I load first works but the other will not, it gives me error: "Unitialized constant Admin::Towers"

I have the following routes setup.

```
namespace :admin do
 #...etc...    

 resources :inspections, only: [:index,:show], controller: 'towers/inspections'
 resources :activities, only: [:index], controller: 'towers/activities'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've namespaced your resources, your controllers should reside within `app/controllers/admin/*` and have a name, i.e. for inspections: `class Admin::InspectionsController`

I'm guessing you would like to have:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :inspections, only: [:index,:show], controller: 'towers/inspections'
  resources :activities, only: [:index], controller: 'towers/activities'
end
```

Comment: yes but I have other functionality that requires it to be nested under towers, not admin